# html5 video javascript controls working everything but firefox on mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

On my page I have a button that on click, toggles the class of that button and then I use an if statement to determine what class is on the button, to decided if I should play or pause the video.

```
<button id="toggle" class="buttonVideoUnactive"></button>  

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("video").load(); 
    $("video").get(0).pause(); 

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("main").fadeToggle(300);
        $("video").fadeToggle(300);
        $("button").toggleClass('buttonVideoUnactive buttonVideoActive'); 


        if ( $( "#toggle" ).hasClass( "buttonVideoUnactive" ) ) {
            console.log("off");
            $("video").load(); 
            $("video").get(0).pause(); 

        }

        if ( $( "#toggle" ).hasClass( "buttonVideoActive" ) ) {
            console.log("on");
            $("video").get(0).play(); 

        }

    });

});
```

My issue is that on firefox on a mac It will not play or pause when button is clicked.It works on every browser except on firefox on a mac. on my fiddle everything works perfect,even on mac! but on my site not so much.. is there a conflict or know reason why this is happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/qteuaoos/

http://www.braven.com/705-speaker#

Comment: If you can set up the video to auto-play (I'm pretty sure `autoplay` is an attribute you can set) will it play at all in Firefox? Just want to verify whether it's a codec issue.

Comment: yes it does play when autoplay is added to video tag directly.

Comment: I just tried both on Firefox 36 on my mac and they both worked perfectly fine. Try clearing your cache and everything just incase its a local issue.

Comment: Hum Im going to try another mac but im still getting not actions after I click the button. I cleared cache.

Comment: It works on another computer, must be my machine. thanks for help.